# How to refresh the headers of CSV::Table?

Tags: ruby, csv

Is there any good way for refreshment of headers in CSV::Table object?

```rb
require 'csv'

txt =<<TXT
"h1","h2","h3"
1,"test",3
2,"test",6
3,"test",9
TXT

table = CSV::parse(txt, headers: true)
table.each do |row|
  row << {"h4" => "additional"}
end
puts table.to_csv
```

**actual**

```
h1, h2,   h3  
1,  test, 3,  additional  
2,  test, 6,  additional  
3,  test, 9,  additional
```

**expected**

```
h1, h2,   h3, h4  
1,  test, 3,  additional  
2,  test, 6,  additional  
3,  test, 9,  additional
```

Comment: when I execute your code, I see `h4` in my output

Comment: Uhh. I see. Year, previous try I also get such kind of results. Which version of ruby and CSV gem using in your computer? I'm using ruby 2.6.0 and CSV 3.0.2.

Comment: ruby 2.5.3p105 and CSV 1.0.0

Comment: I am using lower version than what @LeninRajRajasekaran is using, worked properly! If it is really bug then you should raise it on github.

Comment: Thank you @ray. I'll try to raise a pull request.

Comment: The last version that worked as expected was version 3.0.0. Consider reviewing [the commits between 3.0.0 and 3.0.1](https://github.com/ruby/csv/compare/153d261...1176a56).

Comment: I raise this as [issue #71](https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/71).

Answer (score 0):

Your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/71) has been resolved by the author. You can install the gem from GitHub and it will work the way you expect.

The problem is that you can't easily install the gem with `gem install`. (unless you clone the repo and build the gem and install the gem from your filesystem, but that is not a portable solution) And if you can't use `gem install` then you can't use `require 'csv'` because that will just use the bugged version that you already have installed. (similarly, cloning the repo and using `require '/path/to/csv-3.0.4'` is not a portable solution)

A workaround is to use bundler to install the fixed gem into your bundle path:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'csv', git: 'https://github.com/ruby/csv.git', ref: '7ede8e84a2b8'
```

Then run `bundle install`:

```
Fetching https://github.com/ruby/csv.git
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using csv 3.0.4 from https://github.com/ruby/csv.git (at 7ede8e8@7ede8e8)
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

And run `bundle info csv` to confirm:

```
bundle info csv
  * csv (3.0.4 7ede8e8)
    Summary: CSV Reading and Writing
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/csv
    Path: /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bundler/gems/csv-7ede8e84a2b8
```

Next, change your script to use bundler to load the gems and specify the version of the gem you want to use:

```
# test.rb
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default
gem 'csv', '=3.0.4'

puts CSV::VERSION
```

(you don't call `require 'csv'`; bundler does this for you)

Then run `ruby test.rb` and verify it's using the version of the gem you expect:

```
3.0.4
```

Now modify `test.rb` to include your original code:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default
gem 'csv', '=3.0.4'

txt =<<TXT
"h1","h2","h3"
1,"test",3
2,"test",6
3,"test",9
TXT

table = CSV::parse(txt, headers: true)

puts table.to_csv + "\n"

table.each do |row|
  row << {"h4" => "additional"}
end

puts table.to_csv
```

And run with `ruby test.rb`:

```
h1,h2,h3
1,test,3
2,test,6
3,test,9

h1,h2,h3,h4
1,test,3,additional
2,test,6,additional
3,test,9,additional
```

Now you have a portable solution that will run on any system and load the gem from the git repo at the commit where this fix was implemented.